# Reactjs restful api consumption not working

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to reactjs and i am creating below program to fetch the restful service. but i am getting the typeerror while fetching the service. but in other hand if i am hitting the other URL i am able to get the response. not sure why?

```
 var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      myCollection: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {

     var th = this;


    //   http://codepen.io/jobs.json ---this is working URL


       var myRequest = new Request('http://api.dev.com/myService.svc/data/customernumber/1?format=json');
       fetch(myRequest)      
        .then(function(result) { 
          if(result.ok) {alert(result.status);}
          th.setState({            
            myCollection: result.data.myCollection
          });
        })
        .catch(function(result){
          alert(result);
        })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>

        {this.state.myCollection.map(function(job) {
          return (
            <div>
              <a >
                {job.myAddress}                
              </a>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,  
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the specific error you've got? any cors problem?

try `var myRequest = "http://api.dev.com/myService.svc/data/customernumber/1?format=json";`

Comment: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: also tried no-cors but it is not working. I also tried Authontication but it is not working. Tried Axios to get the response but no luck.

Comment: var myRequest = new Request('http://api.dev.com/myService.svc/data/customernumber/1?format=json', {'mode': 'no-cors'});

Comment: try just use the string as request url, not Request instance, and Headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain')

Comment: var myRequest = new Request('api.dev.com/myService.svc/data/customernumber/1?for‌​mat=json', {'mode': 'no-cors'}, {
 headers: new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
 })
});

Comment: hold on, I will give you an example

Comment: here is part of my project code https://jsbin.com/kubufit/3/edit, maybe not work for you, but you can reference it

Comment: from the code it looks like you have just added the headers there. but it still not working for me.

Comment: Google Chrome... Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Comment: I try 'http://api.dev.com/myService.svc/data/customernumber/1?format=json%27' directly in Chrome, no response there

Comment: I hosted this api is on my local machine. you would not be able to get the response. I am able to get the response if i directly hit the uRL in chrome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help anymore.

Comment: thanks for all your effort. Really appreciate it. Thank you